# How to print out only the number of eslint errors in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, console, output, command-line-interface, eslint

The project I'm working with has a huge code-base, which means that if I do `eslint *.js` in the terminal, I get thousands of lines in the output. I want to tweak this command only to print out the number of errors, not to actually list all the errors one by one.

What to do to make my results similar to this:

```
96 problems
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking a bit more, if you really just want a single number, then create your own formatter that would look something like this.

```
const errorsInFile => (el, currentEl) => el + currentEl.errorCount

module.exports = function (results) {
  return `${results.reduce(errorsInFile, 0)} problems`
}
```

Or just for fun, we could do it functionally with Ramda

```
import { map, pipe, prop, reduce, sum } from 'ramda'

const sumArgs = (...args) => sum(args)
const nProblems = n => `${n} problems`

module.exports = pipe(
  map(prop(‘errorCount’),
  reduce(sumArgs),
  nProblems,
)
```

Comment: Good idea, but this doesn't return the actual number of errors. I tweaked it to actually run through each report, take errorCount and sum it all up.



`const errorCount = results.reduce((el, currentEl) => ({ errorCount: el.errorCount + currentEl.errorCount })).errorCount;`

Comment: You can edit your answer and add my code so I can accept the answer. So just add this `module.exports = function (results) {
  return results.reduce((el, currentEl) => ({ errorCount: el.errorCount + currentEl.errorCount })).errorCount;
};`

Comment: doh, yep your right, I've updated the answer and expanded it to return `${n} problems` :)

Comment: Also thinking a bit more, I think it can be done without the object

Comment: One minor change needed here for this to work - should be `results.reduce(errorsInFile, 0)` so the initial value used is 0 instead of the first element in the results array, which is an object.

Comment: @MichaelHagar good spot, fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```bash
eslint --format compact 2>&1 >/dev/null | egrep '^[0-9]+ problems'
```

Result:

```
169 problems
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find this userful, it will give you the number of each type of error

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-formatter-summary-chart

```
% eslint --format summary-chart src
 
==== Files ====
bar.js : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  33.33%
foo.js : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  66.67%
 
 
==== Rules ====
constructor-super     : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  16.67%
no-cond-assign        : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  16.67%
no-constant-condition : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  16.67%
no-debugger           : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  16.67%
no-unused-vars        : ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  33.33%
```

Comment: Just noticed that is giving percentages, but the source code is super simple, if you want to tweak it to number of issues instead

Comment: Yes, this package was my go-to solution, but unfortunately I couldn't use it simply because I am stuck with node v10.19.0 which makes it impossible for this package to work as it's dependent on a newer node version.

Answer (score 0):

In a shell script (bash or zsh, for example) you can count the lines of errors output by `eslint` using [`wc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix)), and `echo` it to the console.

```
ERRCOUNT=$(eval "eslint | wc -l")
echo $OUTPUT errors
```

Example result:

```
185 errors
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation (https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface), you can run with flag --quiet

```
eslint --quiet 'src/**'
```

Comment: This still prints out errors such as:
   4:1    error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4    indent
   5:1    error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4    indent
   6:1    error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4    indent